# What are the benefits of creating subnets in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, subnet, vpc, google-vpc

As we know the vpc firewall in GCP is a distributed firewall which means it is enforced at host/ vm level so I wanted to understand the benefits or use of creating multiple subnets in GCP.

Comment: Each VPC network consists of one or more IP address range called subnets. Subnets are regional resources, and have IP address ranges associated with them. A network must have at least one subnet before you can use it. Usually, all resources with the same concern/topology should be added in the same subnetwork. Please read through this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/subnets#:~:text=Virtual%20Private%20Cloud%20(VPC)%20networks,subnet%20and%20subnetwork%20are%20synonymous.

Comment: Are you asking about the subnets that Google creates for your project or about creating new subnets? All networks are a subnet of another network with a couple of exceptions for reserved/special networks. A subnet is just a smaller slice of a larger network. Edit your question to clarify what you are asking.